# Improve cardinality estimation when two joined tables have a condition on an identical column

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan

I have a table `foo`, with an association table `foo_associations` with columns `foo_parent` and `foo_child`. `foo` has an column called `department_id`. Any association made through `foo_associations` is guaranteed to only connect `foos` that have the same `department_id`

Due to the way a framework is set up, when you do a join `foo <-> foo_associations <-> foo`, it adds an `department_id = $1` condition for `foo_1.department_id` and for `foo_2.department_id`, respectively. Both of these values get applied twice in the estimation calculation, reducing the estimated amount of rows significantly. This causes bad plans in some circumstances.

I'm a bit short on luck in regard to adjusting the framework and I couldn't find a specific entry that would help me on the statistics in the documentation. Is there a way that I can help the planner out here and tell him that the second condition will not filter out any rows?

Note: Simplified Toy Example, which is reduced to the problem and may not necessarily reflect all design decisions

Comment: I don't think any of the statistics options will help you.  You would need something like cross-table statistics (or maybe cross table CHECK-like constraints) , which currently are unimplemented.